# comparison of value on basis of key in list of maps

Tags: java, comparator

I have a map of string to String, and I want to sort the **maps** based on thier value for the kay `F`, but my code fails doing so. please advise.

```
    Map<String, String> h = null;
    Map<String, String> h1 = null;
    Map<String, String> h2 = null;
    listSummaryMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    h = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h.put("SUCCESS", "27");
    h.put("TOTAL_HOTELS", "86");
    h.put("F", "86");
    h.put("RESERVATION_MODE", "86");
    h.put("PARTNER_NAME", "86");

    h1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h1.put("SUCCESS", "27");
    h1.put("TOTAL_HOTELS", "86");
    h1.put("F", "36");
    h1.put("RESERVATION_MODE", "86");
    h1.put("PARTNER_NAME", "86");

    h2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h2.put("SUCCESS", "27");
    h2.put("TOTAL_HOTELS", "86");
    h2.put("F", "28");
    h2.put("RESERVATION_MODE", "86");
    h2.put("PARTNER_NAME", "86");

    listSummaryMap .add(h);
    listSummaryMap .add(h1);
    listSummaryMap .add(h2);


    Collections.sort(listSummaryMap , new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
            return o2.get("F").compareTo(o1.get("F"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Collections.addAll(listSummaryMap, h, h1, h2);` after all maps are created.

Comment: Thanks Jekin Kalariya ,Eran , everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `String`s to `Integer`s and compare as `Integer`s :

```
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o2.get("F")).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o1.get("F")));
    }
```

This is assuming the `"F"` key is always present in the `Map`s, and its value can always be parsed to an `Integer`.

BTW, I don't see where you add the `Map`s to `listSummaryMap`. Did you forget to include that code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Need to convert String to integer first and then compare will work like this.

```
Collections.sort(listSummaryMap , new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
                Integer a=Integer.parseInt(o2.get("F"));
                Integer b=Integer.parseInt(o1.get("F"));
                return b.compareTo(a);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the maps to your list and the map h3 is never initialized. That taken apart your code already works as is but sorts the maps from the highest id to the lowest. If you change your comparison line to that:

```
Collections.sort(listSummaryMap , new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        return o1.get("F").compareTo(o2.get("F"));
    }
});
```

Then it will sort your maps by "F" from the lowest to the highest value.

Hope it helps